# Porque este @Html.DropDownListFor não aceita os htmlAttributes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net, dropdown

Tenho uma View que será somente leitura em alguns casos. E não quero usar javascript, pois pode ser desabilitado no lado do usuário.
Em fim...

Quando faço isso (para testes) funciona perfeitamente.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="input-group col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaSelectList, "Id", "Descricao"), new { @class = "form-control input-sm", @disabled ="disabled" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando tento passar os atributos HTML por variável, como a seguir, não funciona:

```
var attribs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
attribs.Add("class", "form-control input-sm");
if (ViewBag.ReadOnly)
{
    attribs.Add("disabled", "disabled");
}
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="input-group col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaSelectList, "Id", "Descricao"), new { htmlAttributes = @attribs })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que a única coisa que mudo é:

*@class = "form-control input-sm", @disabled ="disabled"*

por

*htmlAttributes = @attribs*

E o que me deixa curioso é que isso sempre funcionou para mim. Inclusive na mesma View funciona perfeitamente para os @Html.EditorFor. Só este DropDownListFor que não está recebendo o @attribs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdStatusRegistro, new SelectList(ViewBag.ListaSelectList, "Id", "Descricao"), htmlAttributes: attribs)
```

Aparentemente é só um erro na passagem do parâmetro.

Comment: Obrigado! Realmente funcionou. Mas saberia me dizer o porque nos EditorFor não tive problema? Afinal qual a maneira correta... @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCadastro, new { htmlAttributes = @attribs })   ou   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataCadastro, htmlAttributes: @attribs)?

Comment: A maneira correta é  `htmlAttributes: @attribs`, não sei te dizer porque funcionou da outra forma no EditorFor mas declarando um novo objeto com uma propriedade htmlAttributes (`new { htmlAttributes = ... }`) não é uma sobrecarga válida. O certo é um objeto com os atributos no tipo chave/valor ou um dicionário <string,object>